# div inside header / near page top / doesn't show after 2 click events, while it's footer twin works - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I made 2 bars which should behave identically when you click to minimize / restore.

While the footer bar works 100% as it should, the restore button in the header doesn't show after minimizing + restoring for the 1st time. Interestingly, it's still functional, but the restore button is invisible and mainly outside of the screen. I don't know why that happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/YMeRQ/

```
$('.minimize').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
    $(this).parent('.bar').animate({'height':'20px'}, {duration : 200});
    $(this).siblings('.restore').animate({'z-index':'10000', 'opacity':'1'}, {duration : 200});
});
$('.restore').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.bar').animate({'height':'40px'}, {duration : 200});
    $('#restore-h') > $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'bottom':'1px', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
    $('#restore-f') > $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'top':'1px', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
    $(this).siblings('.minimize').animate({'z-index':'10000', 'opacity':'1'}, {duration : 200});
});
```

Comment: Can you be more clear, because this seems to work... Only button disappearing is your problem?

Comment: `#restore-h` div is the problem. it doesn't show after you minimize, then restore, then minimize again the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this seems to work when you don't animate `top` and `bottom`.

So your code for:

```
$('#restore-h') > $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'bottom':'1px', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
$('#restore-f') > $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'top':'1px', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
```

should be:

```
$('#restore-h') > $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
$('#restore-f') > $(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YMeRQ/1/)**

Comment: still the same. I think if css and z-index are the problem, `#restore-f` would also disappear.

Comment: hmm... okay will have to try something else... so exactly your div hides on second restore right?

Comment: yes. what's confusing is that `#restore-h` and `#restore-f` are completely identical / symmetrical, but they don't behave the same.

Comment: holly sht, it does! finally, I'm messing with this for hours. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It works, it's just that after the second click, you apply to 'restore-h' a css style of 'top: 1px;'. So your arrow is not visible because it is pushed upwards.

Also, I"m not really sure what you're trying to do here with the '>' character:

```
$('#restore-h') > $(this)
```

In your '.restore' click event, you should use an IF...ELSE Statement and check if the THIS selector has the ID you want to modify. Because, I believe that in it's present form, your code executes both of these statements to the current element:

```
$(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'bottom':'1px', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
$(this).animate({'z-index':'-1', 'top':'1px', 'opacity':'0'}, {duration : 200});
```

Comment: Also the click zone of your arrow is way too small. You should expend it more

Comment: maybe I'm missing the obvious, but even when I replace the last line in $(.minimize).click with `$('#restore-h').animate({'z-index':'10000', 'bottom':'1px', 'opacity':'1'}, {duration : 200});`, it still behaves the same. I also tried with more straight-forward selectors, nothing I tried helps. Have you made it to work? Can you edit the fiddle?

Comment: @ j809: yeah, it was suppose to be haha, but then I realized some more explanation was needed so I was in the process of editing it

Comment: yeah, that selector is maybe not necessary, but with or without it, my result is still the same. and if "if" is needed, I think `#restore-f` would need it too.